# Javascript - how can I make links from text excluding any already made link?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I make as link from a url found in text, but excluding any already made link found?
Can you help with the proper regex?

```
  function makeurl(text) {
  var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
  return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
    return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
  })
}

var check = 'Hello <a href="https://www.xyyyyy.co">cick here</a> to visit our website http://google.x';

console.log (makeurl(check) )
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9L30zotx/

I want to change only http://google.x but leave as is the already made html for [www.xyyyyy.co](http://www.xyyyyy.co)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can check if there is a space before the link (or the start in case the link is at the beginning of the text) using `([\s]|^)` at the beginning of your regex (`/([\s]|^)(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g`).

Comment: Answer is sufficient for OP to try different suggestions and debug based on that

Comment: Thank you! Really effective

Answer (score 0):

If the anchor text **isn't a url** itself, then you can easily parse out the HTML content, and then you'll have only pure text.

Try the following code,

```js
function makeurl(text) {
  var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
  document.body.innerHTML = text; // taking document.body as example
  text = document.body.innerText;
  
  return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
    return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
  });
}

var check = 'Hello <a href="https://www.xyyyyy.co">click here</a> to visit our website http://google.x';

console.log(makeurl(check))
```